# Can I store patterns as values in SQL table and then try to match a value?

Tags: sql, regex

I'm looking for something that works similar to LIKE operator but on the opposite direction.

for example I would like to have a table like that:

```
pattern, num
a% , 1
b% , 2
```

and I'm looking for an operator that the term `abc` will match the first line and `bac` will match the second.

Is it possible using sql?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Undecided yet. I'm thinking of using Amazon RDS so any of those options will be good: MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Amazon Aurora, or MariaDB

Comment: If you have a suggestion for a better option for this use-case I will be happy to hear...

Comment: If you tag the dbms used you will get much better attention, and better answers - faster!!! (Most probably you can expect a product specific answer...)

Comment: Why do you think that LIKE doesn't work? `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE 'abc' LIKE pattern`

Comment: @haytem: Ha-ha, 30 seconds faster :-)

Comment: Yes you are getting slow Dieter :)

Comment: @dnoeth you are correct. wasn't aware that like works both ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this quite easily.  This is not a regex issue, given that your patterns look more like `like` patterns.

The query would look like:

```
select t.*
from t
where 'abc' like t.pattern;
```

You an use similar logic in an `on` clause, if you are joining tables.